# Como linkar a SDL2 estaticamente

Tags: c++, sdl

Com um projeto simples da sdl, apenas mostra uma janela vazia. Estou usando o seguinte CMake(no CLion) :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(AprendendoCpp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR C:/Linguagens/Cpp/Libs/SDL/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2)
set(SDL2_LIBRARY C:/Linguagens/Cpp/Libs/SDL/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${SDL2_LIBRARY})
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(AprendendoCpp ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(AprendendoCpp  -lSDL2 -lSDL2main)
```

Ele compila normalmente, mas o exe fica dependendo de uma dll, SDL2.dll . Na source existem a **SDL2.lib** e **SDL2main.lib** como faço pra usar elas e compilar estaticamente ?